# IsolatedStorageSettings ApplicationSettings for Windows Phone app 8 updates

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Are the settings stored by a Windows Phone 8 app saved when the app gets updated through AppStore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IsolatedStorageSettings provide a convenient way to store user specific data as key-value pairs in a local IsolatedStorageFile with an lifespan of the application.
You can find more about [IsolatedStorageSettings Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

So the answer is that Windows Phone app will save any data saved after app update. If you uninstall app you lose all your data from IsolatedStorageSettings.